# Show that w ∈ span(v1,v2,…,vm)

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

Going through some old exams and found this problem that i cant seem to get my head around and i couldnt find any solutions for it either.

Suppose , n≥m, so that $\overrightarrow{v_{1}},......,\overrightarrow{v_{m}}$ is linearly independent  in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $\overrightarrow{w}$∈ $\mathbb{R}^n$. And we also suppose that $\overrightarrow{v_{1}}-\overrightarrow{w},......,\overrightarrow{v_{m}}-\overrightarrow{w} $ is linearly dependant.

Show that $\overrightarrow{w}$ ∈ span$(\overrightarrow{v_{1}},......,\overrightarrow{v_{m}})$

Comment: Hint:  Consider a dependence $\sum \lambda_i(\vec {v_i}-\vec {w_\,})=0$ with the $\lambda_i$  not all $0$. Argue that $\sum \lambda_i$ can not be $0$ and deduce an expression for $\vec w$ in terms of the $\vec {v_i}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $w = 0$ we are done. Suppose $w \not= 0$

There exist some $a_{1},a_{2},\cdots, a_{n}$ not all null such that $\sum_{i=1}^{n}(v_{i} -w)a_{i} = 0$

Then we have that $\sum_{i = 1}^{n} v_{i}a_{i} = w\sum_{i = 1}^{n}a_{i}$

if $\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_{i} = 0\implies \sum_{i = 1}^{n} v_{i}a_{i} = 0 \implies$ all $a_{i} = 0$ because $\{v_{1},\cdots,v_{n}\}$ are linearly independent, this is a contradiction because we had that they were not all null.

Then $\sum_{i=1}^{n} a_{i} = a \not= 0$ and thus $\sum_{i = 1}^{n} v_{i}(a_{i}a^{-1}) = w$

Thus $w \in $ span$(v_{1},\cdots,v_{n})$